# Are there TRAMP mode log files? If so, how to access them?

Tags: tramp, logging

Having here some troubles with TRAMP mode and already set `(customize-set-variable 'tramp-verbose 6 "Enable remote command traces")` in `.emacs` file.

But main problem is that Emacs is stuck in TRAMP mode, and debug buffer can't be accessed.

Hangs while copying large files via scp to remote to local network, it hangs on Encoding in base64. Already set (setq tramp-inline-compress-start-size "800000000"), (setq tramp-copy-size-limit "800000000") and (customize-set-variable 'tramp-verbose 6 "Enable remote command traces").

Anyway there would be log files to access?

Comment: Can you provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem? Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? (If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.)

Comment: Hangs while copying large files via `scp` to remote to local network, it hangs on `Encoding in base64`. Already set `(setq tramp-inline-compress-start-size "800000000")`, `(setq tramp-copy-size-limit "800000000")` and `(customize-set-variable 'tramp-verbose 6 "Enable remote command traces")`.

Comment: Please put all such info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: Just have done it.

Comment: When Tramp hangs, you might be able to interrupt it by several `C-g`. Does this work? You will see then a buffer starting with `*debug tramp/`

Comment: Yes, that's working, corrected the problem.

Comment: Currently accepted answer do not deliver on the actual request to log Tramp traces to a file. I have a similar problem, but Ctrl+g doesn't work becase my Emacs hangs completely. So other answers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it as brother up there said, we are having similar problem here and `CRTL + g` works swiftly, then just check debug buffer.

Comment: The question asks for log files. This is a workaround.