# Log Tramp traces to a file

Tags: debugging, tramp

I am experiencing some Emacs Tramp connection problems and want to ask for help. However in my case Emacs hangs completely because of Tramp and there is no way I can access Tramp **debug** files. (it is not responsive to Ctrl-g)

Is there a way to log those trace to a file?

PS I am aware of [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53321/are-there-tramp-mode-log-files-if-so-how-to-access-them). However the answer accepted there completely ignores the request to log to a file and suggests to interrupt the process with Ctrl-g.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Very good question. Currently it is not supported by Tramp, but I take it as feature request, and I will work on it next days. Shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: Well, I've added this to Tramp, available in both Emacs and Tramp git repositories. There is a new user option `tramp-debug-to-file`. When non-nil, the debug buffer will be mirrored to a file under the `/tmp/` directory.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I am going to try it and submit a bug report using it.